# ADD Multiple UserID's into a column

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I want to add multiple UsersID's into a column. Column type is "People and Group". Everytime it's inserted an userid, he smashes the other one, staying only one.
Can someone help me?
Thank You.

```
//URL LIST ID
var urllistid = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var listaid = urllistid.get('M_ListID');

//GET SITE URL
var context = new SP.ClientContext();
var relativeWebUrl = context.get_url();
var siteURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + relativeWebUrl ;

//GET USER ID
var UserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

//GET ITEM ID FROM URL
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var myParam = urlParams.get('M_ID');

//ADD USERID IN COLUMN "QuemLeu" FROM A SPECIFIC ITEM
var listType = 'SP.Data.' + encodeURIComponent('Páginas') + 'ListItem(myParam)';

jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Páginas')/items('" + myParam +"')?$select=ID,Title,QuemLeu/Id&$expand=QuemLeu",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var userIdArray = [];
        if(data.d){
            if(data.d.QuemLeu.results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.QuemLeu.results.length; i++) {
                    userIdArray.push(data.d.QuemLeu.results[i].Id);
                }
            }
        }
        userIdArray.push(UserId);
        var fields = {
            "__metadata": { 'type': listType},
            "Title": "teste",
            "QuemLeu": {"results": userIdArray }
        }
        updateItem(fields);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

function updateItem(fields) {
    jQuery.ajax({  
        url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Páginas')/items('" + myParam +"')",  
        type: "POST",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest" : document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"  
        },  
        data: JSON.stringify(fields),  

        success: function(data) {  
            console.log(data.d.results);  
        },  
        error: function(error) {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to get the collection of all previous users added in that field and then add current user id in that collection and update that item.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Ok, How Can I possible do that?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I edit my post with the recent code, is something wrong with it, could you please try to reproduce in your side and test it?
Where it is written "Páginas" is the name of the list "Pages" from sharepoint and "QuemLeu" is the name of the column of type "Person Group". Displays this error "return originalSend.apply(this, arguments);"
Thank you!

Comment: At which line and in which file it is throwing this error?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I think it is ajax.ts:153

Comment: Have you used any typescript file with that name?

Comment: I just put the code in web console

Comment: @GaneshSanap Display an error when function updateItem try to send fields as an argument.

Comment: Add breakpoint in the success of first call and try to debug the code.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I dont know how to do it, can you help me, please?

Comment: Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).

Comment: Is this line right?
 var listType = 'SP.Data.' + encodeURIComponent('Páginas') + 'ListItem(myParam)'; Should not be 'ListItem('+myParam+')'?

Comment: You need to provide `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` property of list in listType. Read more about it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest) in "Retrieving lists and list properties with REST" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below Code:

```
function veruser(){

    //URL LIST ID
    var urllistid = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var listaid = urllistid.get('M_ListID');

    //GET THE LIST NAME FROM LIST ID
    var lista;
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listaid);
    clientContext.load(oList,"Title");
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        lista = this.oList.get_title();
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    //END GET THE LIST NAME FROM LIST ID    

    //GET SITE URL
    var context = new SP.ClientContext();
    var relativeWebUrl = context.get_url();
    var siteURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + relativeWebUrl ;

    //GET USER ID
    var UserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

    //GET ITEM ID FROM URL
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var myParam = urlParams.get('M_ID');

    //ADD USERID IN COLUMN "QuemLeuId" FROM A SPECIFIC ITEM
    var listType = 'SP.Data.' + encodeURIComponent(lista) + 'ListItem(myParam)';

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + lista +"')/items('" + myParam +"')?$select=ID,Title,QuemLeuId/Id&$expand=QuemLeuId",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var userIdArray = [];
            if(data.d){
                if(data.d.QuemLeuId.results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.QuemLeuId.results.length; i++) {
                        userIdArray.push(data.d.QuemLeuId.results[i].Id);
                    }
                }
            }
            userIdArray.push(UserId);
            var fields = {
                "__metadata": { 'type': listType},
                "Title": "teste",
                "QuemLeuId": {"results": userIdArray }
            }
            updateItem(fields);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    function updateItem(fields) {
        $.ajax({  
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + lista +"')/items('" + myParam +"')",  
            type: "POST",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"  
            },  
            data: JSON.stringify(fields),  

            success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data.d.results);  
            },  
            error: function(error) {  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working but display this error "$ is not a function" in this line " "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()," when I write in web console.

Comment: You need to add jquery file for that. Also you can use `document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value` instead of `$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must send data to endpoint in following format:

```
var fields = {
    "__metadata": { 'type': listType},
    "Title": "teste",
    "QuemLeuId": {
       "results": [
         UserId, OtherId1, OtherId2
       ]
    }
}
```

You must pass array in results property.

Comment: Hello, i've this "var UserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;" to get the current userId, how can I post the current user in 

"results": [
         UserId, OtherId1, OtherId2
       ]

I only have one variable, how can I add multiple userId's using one variable?

Comment: Please see Ganesh Sanap answer. I think it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo for your reference, multiple user id needs to pass an array collection with user id like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": 'SP.Data.MyList3ListItem'},
        "Title": "alue change",
          "QuemLeuId": {"results": [12,9] }

    };

$.ajax({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList3')/items",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    data: JSON.stringify(item),   
    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
});  
</script>
```

Here is the returned Json:

[image]