# See if UserId exists in column

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

What can I do to see if the current User ID already exists in the column ("QuemLeuId") of type "Person Group" for particular Item in the list?

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log("Dentro da PageLayout");
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    console.log(userId);

    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var myParam = urlParams.get('M_ID');
    console.log(myParam);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Páginas')/items('" + myParam +"')",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Where do you want to check this? On display/edit form of list? And what is the name of your person and group column?

Comment: The name is "QuemLeuId".

Comment: Is multiple selection allowed on this column?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Páginas')/items('" + myParam +"')?$select=ID,Title,QuemLeuId/Id&$expand=QuemLeuId",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d){
            if(data.d.QuemLeuId.Id == userId){
                console.log("User Found.");
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

If Multiple Selection is allowed on Person or Group Field then you need to traverse the `data.d.QuemLeuId.results` array and check if the user is found or not(Use below code inside `success` function):

```
if(data.d){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.QuemLeuId.results.length; i++){
        if(data.d.QuemLeuId.results[i].Id == userId){
            console.log("User Found.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working! Is it normal display this " 'length' of undefined" when it doesnt found any userId in the column? Thank you.

Comment: To avoid that error, you can add one more check like `if(data.d.QuemLeuId.results){}` before for loop. please upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you! I also have this ticket, could you take a look? Link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254202/add-multiple-userids-into-a-column, I think you can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax request returns the item successfully you should be able to check the person/group column with `data.d.QuemLeuId == userId` in case of single user column or `data.d.QuemLeuId.indexOf(userId) > -1` if it's a multi-user column.

Comment: I used this code inside success:
if(data.d.QuemLeu.indexOf(userId) > -1){
 console.log("OK!");
}
And display an error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". What should I do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Then your user column is probably single-user/group and you can check directly using `data.d.QuemLeuId == userId`. I'd recommend calling `console.log(data);` first thing in your success function so you can easily see the structure of the web service response

Answer (score 0):

Use REST api to filter based on user filed, check if data length returned >0.

19 is user ID.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist3')/items?$select=Title,QuemLeuId/Id&$expand=QuemLeuId&$filter=QuemLeuId/Id eq 19
```

Comment: In your example is searching for the UserID in the all list. What I want is search in column ('QuemLeuId') but for a specific item. Should I do like .../items('" + itemid +"')/?$select=Title...?. Thank you.